# Word Replacement in docx

Tags: python, docx

I want having a docx document as a template, to scan and replace some words in it with other words.
I have done so successfully with txt but with the word i cant do it.
I have written the following code

First i have created a dictionary where the keys are the'oldwords' and the appropriate values the 'new words'

```
dict={'Name1': 'Billy', 'Vlan': '12345', 'ptp_ip_1': '10.10.10.1', 'ptp_ip_2': '10.10.10.2'}

d=docx.document(r'C:\path\Template.docx')

for p in range(0,len(d.paragraphs)):
    par=d.paragraphs[p].text
    for i in dict.keys():
        par.replace(i,dict[i])
```

The problem is the it prints each line 4 times (the number of key/pairs in the dict)

eg

```
'address ptp_ip_1/mask'
'address ptp_ip_1/mask'
'address 10.10.10.1/mask'
'address ptp_ip_1/mask'
'next-hop ptp_ip_2'
'next-hop ptp_ip_2'
'next-hop ptp_ip_2'
'next-hop 10.10.10.2'
```

i then tried first to see if the key that represents the 'oldword' is at the line and if it is only then to replace the string but the result was that i only printed the lines that i replaced-not the ones that remained intact

```
for p in range(0,len(d.paragraphs)):
    par=d.paragraphs[p].text
    for i in list(dict.keys()):
        if i in par:
            par.replace(i,dict[i])
        else: continue
```

any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the Python-OOXML library for handling docx.

Comment: Hi, first thing: `dict` is a reserved keyword in python, you should not use it as a variable name (replace it with something else). As to your problem, I think you're modifying something you're iterating over and that may be the reason why it behaves strangely. You'd better modify a copy of the object you're iterating over. Last thing (not related to your problem): your loop could be improved, I think, writing something like `for p in d.paragraphs: par = d.text` etc.